# Installing Monarc server in an Ubuntu 18.04 docker container throws laminas dependency plugin error

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to setup Monarc inside a docker container, I'm at the stage of running composer. But this unfortunately throws the following error:

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    Package operations: 79 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
      - Installing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (1.0.3): Loading from cache
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PRE_COMMAND_RUN' in /var/lib/monarc/fo/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php:63
    Stack trace:
    #0 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(378): Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPlugin::getSubscribedEvents()
    #1 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(239): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->addSubscriber(Object(Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPlugin))
    #2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(205): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin(Object(Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPlugin))
    #3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/PluginInstaller.php(63): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->registerPackage(Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage), true)
    #4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(173): Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller->install(Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository), Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage))
    #5 /usr/sha in /var/lib/monarc/fo/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php on line 63

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PRE_COMMAND_RUN' in /var/lib/monarc/fo/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php:63
    Stack trace:
    #0 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(378): Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPlugin::getSubscribedEvents()
    #1 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(239): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->addSubscriber(Object(Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPlugin))
    #2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(205): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin(Object(Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPlugin))
    #3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/PluginInstaller.php(63): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->registerPackage(Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage), true)
    #4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php(173): Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller->install(Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository), Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage))
    #5 /usr/sha in /var/lib/monarc/fo/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php on line 63
```

I'm following the guide available here: https://github.com/monarc-project/MonarcAppFO/blob/master/INSTALL/INSTALL.ubuntu1804.md.

My dockerfile for this section currently looks like (failing on the composer line with the above error):

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/monarc/fo
RUN git clone https://github.com/monarc-project/MonarcAppFO.git /var/lib/monarc/fo

WORKDIR /var/lib/monarc/fo
RUN mkdir -p data/cache
RUN mkdir -p data/LazyServices/Proxy
RUN chmod -R g+w data
RUN composer install -o
```

The line regarding running it as root/sudo seems fine looking at the link. Outside of that I am completely lost as to what's going wrong here.

Comment: Hi Carling, did you eventually figured out this error? I ran into the exact same problem and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not, StackOverflow was my last hope.

Answer (score 1):

Your composer version is outdated.

Just Upgrade composer, and try again.